# Derivatives using indexed variables

Tags: maxima, calculus

As an example I want to try to find the partial derivatives of

```
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
```

in Maxima. (The expected output would be `\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = 2x_k`) I have tried following, but it seems the indexed variables are not handled as I expected, can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

The same command works if you replace `n` and `k` with actual numbers, but not in this form:

```
f(x) := 1/2 * sum( x[i]^2, i, 1, n);
print(diff(f(x),x[k]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02syMxN/P8/TaNCU8HKVsFQ30hBS6G4NFdDoSI6MzbOSEchU0fBUEchT9Oaq6AoM69EIyUzLU0DpF6nIjo7VlPT@v9/AA)

Comment: Maxima doesn't know how to handle that with builtin functions. I wrote a couple of small packages to handle it -- search for diff_sum.mac and sum_kron_delta.mac. I will post an answer which makes use of those functions in the next day or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maxima can't handle derivative with respect to a indexed variable by default. I wrote a couple of small packages to handle these problems. Perhaps this is useful to you.

See: https://pastebin.com/MmYJRqCq (sum_kron_delta, summation of Kronecker delta)
and: https://pastebin.com/UGCPgvAn (diff_sum, derivative of summation wrt indexed variable)

Here's an example applied to your problem. I'll assume you have downloaded the code above to your computer.

```
(%i1) load ("sum_kron_delta.mac");
(%o1)                         sum_kron_delta.mac
(%i2) load ("diff_sum.mac");
(%o2)                            diff_sum.mac
(%i3) 'diff ('sum (x[i]^2, i, 1, n), x[j]);
                             n
                            ====
                            \
(%o3)                     2  >    x  kron_delta(i, j)
                            /      i
                            ====
                            i = 1
```

Note that you have to write `'diff('sum(...` that is, with the quote mark `'` to indicate that `diff` and `sum` are nouns (formal expressions) instead of verbs (functions which are called). This is necessary in the implementation of `diff_sum` and `sum_kron_delta` because they work with simplification rules. (It's a long story, which I can explain if there's interest.)

I see we got the kron_delta summation, but we need to cause the simplification rules to be applied. We could also write `expand(%, 0, 0)` here instead of `''%`.

```
(%i4) ''%;
(%o4) 2 (if (1 <= j) and (j <= n) and %elementp(j, integers) then x  else 0)
                                                                   j
```

At this point we have the final result, which we can simplify further with additional data.

```
(%i5) assume (j >= 1, j <= n);
(%o5)                          [j >= 1, n >= j]
(%i6) ''%o4;
(%o6)            2 (if %elementp(j, integers) then x  else 0)
                                                    j
(%i7) declare (j, integer);
(%o7)                                done

(%i8) ''%o6;
(%o8)                                2 x
                                        j
```

If this seems fruitful to you, I'll be happy to go into details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed! I will look into the details soon, and come back If I have further questions!